# how to calculate a quadratic equation that best fits a set of given data

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algebra, polynomial-math

I have a vector X of 20 real numbers and a vector Y of 20 real numbers.

I want to model them as

```
y = ax^2+bx + c
```

How to find the value of 'a' , 'b' and 'c'
and best fit quadratic equation.

Given Values

```
X = (x1,x2,...,x20)
Y = (y1,y2,...,y20)
```

i need a formula or procedure to find  following values

```
a = ???
b = ???
c = ???
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Everything @Bartoss said is right, +1. I figured I just add a practical implementation here, without QR decomposition. You want to evaluate the values of a,b,c such that the distance between measured and fitted data is minimal. You can pick as measure

```
sum(ax^2+bx + c -y)^2)
```

where the sum is over the elements of vectors x,y.

Then, a minimum implies that the derivative of the quantity with respect to each of a,b,c is zero:

```
d (sum(ax^2+bx + c -y)^2) /da =0
d (sum(ax^2+bx + c -y)^2) /db =0
d (sum(ax^2+bx + c -y)^2) /dc =0
```

these equations are

```
2(sum(ax^2+bx + c -y)*x^2)=0
2(sum(ax^2+bx + c -y)*x)  =0
2(sum(ax^2+bx + c -y))    =0
```

Dividing by 2, the above can be rewritten as

```
a*sum(x^4) +b*sum(x^3) + c*sum(x^2) =sum(y*x^2)
a*sum(x^3) +b*sum(x^2) + c*sum(x)   =sum(y*x)
a*sum(x^2) +b*sum(x)   + c*N        =sum(y)
```

where `N=20` in your case. A simple code in python showing how to do so follows.

```
from numpy import random, array
from scipy.linalg import solve
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
a, b, c = 6., 3., 4.
N = 20
x = random.rand((N))
y = a * x ** 2 + b * x + c
y += random.rand((20)) #add a bit of noise to make things more realistic

x4 = (x ** 4).sum()
x3 = (x ** 3).sum()
x2 = (x ** 2).sum()
M = array([[x4, x3, x2], [x3, x2, x.sum()], [x2, x.sum(), N]])
K = array([(y * x ** 2).sum(), (y * x).sum(), y.sum()])
A, B, C = solve(M, K)

print 'exact values     ', a, b, c
print 'calculated values', A, B, C

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'b.', label='data')
ax.plot(x, A * x ** 2 + B * x + C, 'r.', label='estimate')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

A much faster way to implement solution is to use a nonlinear least squares algorithm. This will be faster to write, but not faster to run. Using the one provided by `scipy`,

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
def f(arg):
    a,b,c=arg
    return a*x**2+b*x+c-y

(A,B,C),_=leastsq(f,[1,1,1])#you must provide a first guess to start with in this case.
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a [linear least squares problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29). I think the easiest method which gives accurate results is [QR decomposition using Householder reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_Householder_reflections). It is not something to be explained in a stackoverflow answer, but I hope you will find all that is needed with this links.

If you never heard about these before and don't know how it connects with you problem:

```
A = [[x1^2, x1, 1]; [x2^2, x2, 1]; ...]
Y = [y1; y2; ...]
```

Now you want to find `v = [a; b; c]` such that `A*v` is as close as possible to `Y`, which is exactly what least squares problem is all about.